# javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly

I have 2 Wildfly 14 instances running on the same Windows server EC2 instance. One is making a request to another:

```
List<Long> ids = ...
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/test");
boolean put = target.request().put(Entity.entity(ids, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), boolean.class);
```

The endpoint on the other server is:

```
@PUT
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean prepareGame(List<Long> ids) {
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting

```
17:30:05,640 ERROR [stderr] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-2) javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

17:30:05,641 ERROR [stderr] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:223)

17:30:05,641 ERROR [stderr] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:191)

17:30:05,641 ERROR [stderr] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:463)

17:30:05,641 ERROR [stderr] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.put(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:207)

(at the line: boolean put = target.request()... )
```

When I run these on my local machine it works, so i suspect a configuration issue and not a code issue, but I don't know.

The amazon instance allows all outgoing traffic and all incoming TCP traffic on 8080 where the server is listening (`jboss.http.port:8080`). The firewall on the machine also allows this traffic. I have tested that traffic is accepted there via sending a request from my local machine to the remote server with `client.target("http://x.x.x.x:8080/...");` where x.x.x.x is the public ip of the instance. There was no problem.

What would cause this error on the amazon instance but not on my local machine since the address is localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer: the `Startup Poller` and `Shutdown Poller` were (under "Server State Detectors") were set to `Management Service` instead of `Web Port`. This happens, i think, when the `Behavior profile`/Server Adapter profile is set to `Controlled By: Managment Operations` instead of `Filesystem and shell operations`.

I don't know how the poller works or why it causes this error, but that was the solution.